# Как узнать была ли замена по шаблону в режиме, когда Perl like sed?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Есть ли возможность вернуть из Perl exit code отличный от 0, если не произошло замены текста, когда Perl работает в режиме *sed* с опциями `-pe`?

В этом примере хотелось бы вернуть не ноль, для дальнейшего code workflow в SHELL скрипте:

```
echo "xxx xxx" | perl -pe 's/yyy/zzz/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор замены возвращает количество произведенных замен, поэтому мы можем посчитать их в переменной. Это происходит в скрытом цикле, который добавляет ключ `-p`, поэтому сразу вернуть это количество не получится. Мы можем перехватить момент завершения программы создав блок END, в котором можно менять код завершения программы, находящийся в `$?`.

```
echo "xxx xxx" | perl -pe '$c+=s/yyy/zzz/; END { $?=$c }' && echo "No replacement"
```

Данный пример выведет "No replacement", так как замены не произошли.

Comment: Круто! Спасибо!

Comment: @Mike, а если замена произойдёт, всё что после && не отработает?

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk Конечно. `&&` в unix shell выполняет следующую команду только если предыдущая вернула ноль (в противоположность ее поведению в большинстве языков программирования).  Можете поэкспериментировать https://ideone.com/ojgpGx (на "ошибка выполнения" не обращайте внимание, ideone ненулевой код возврата считает ошибкой)